# The component for route 'ActivityFeed' must be a React component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have looked through various similar posts here on SO regarding similar issue, but none of the answers solved it for me.

This is the full error:

[image]

So in my `src/navigation/feed/stack.js` it's being defined like so:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import ActivityFeed from 'activity-feed/session-user/screens/Main';
import HamburgerButton from 'navigation-components/HamburgerButton';
import HeaderTitle from 'navigation-components/HeaderTitle';
import ActionAlertIndicator from 'navigation-components/ActionAlertIndicator';
import * as navConfig from '../config';
import * as cache from 'utils/cache';

const stack = StackNavigator(
  {
    ActivityFeed: {
      screen: ActivityFeed,
      navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
        header: (
          <HeaderTitle
            headerLeft={() => (
              <HamburgerButton
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}
              />
            )}
            headerRight={() => (
              <ActionAlertIndicator
                onPress={() => {
                  cache.setRouteStarter('MainDrawer');
                  navigation.navigate('ActionAlertsStack');
                }}
              />
            )}
          />
        ),
      }),
    },
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: {
      ...navConfig.defaultStackConfig,
    },
  }
);

export default stack;
```

The actual component or screen is defined like so inside of `src/activity-feed/session-user/screens/Main.js`:

```js
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react';
import {
  FlatList,
  StyleSheet,
  AppState,
  Platform,
  Dimensions,
  View,
  Alert,
} from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import OneSignal from 'react-native-onesignal';
import {Loading, SwippableCard, BottomAlert} from 'common-components';
import EmptyState from 'activity-feed/session-user/components/EmptyState';
import EventFeedCard from 'events/components/EventFeedCard';
import SurveyBallotFeedCard from 'surveys-ballots/components/FeedCard';
import MicroSurvey from 'surveys-ballots/components/MicroSurvey';
import ActionAlertFeedCard from 'action-alerts/components/ActionAlertFeedCard';
import MissingAddressCard from 'action-alerts/components/MissingAddressCard';
import ArticleFeedCard from 'articles/components/ArticleFeedCard';
import GetInvolvedFeedCard from 'account-settings/components/GetInvolvedFeedCard';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {
  fetchFeed,
  handleContentSwipe,
  undoSwipeAction,
  hideUndoAlert,
} from 'activity-feed/actions';
import {setSelectedEvent} from 'events/actions';
import {setSelectedSurvey} from 'surveys-ballots/actions';
import {setSelectedAlert, getCampaignDetails} from 'action-alerts/actions';
import * as cache from 'utils/cache';
import {setSelectedArticle} from 'articles/actions';
import {
  handleUpdateTopics,
  handleUpdateGetInvoved,
} from 'account-settings/preferencesActions';
import {scale} from 'react-native-size-matters';
import {emptyStateStyles} from 'theme';

const {height} = Dimensions.get('window');

export class ActivityFeed extends PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    displayAlert: PropTypes.bool,
    feed: PropTypes.array,
    fetchFeed: PropTypes.func,
    getCampaignDetails: PropTypes.func,
    handleContentSwipe: PropTypes.func,
    handleUpdateGetInvoved: PropTypes.func,
    handleUpdateTopics: PropTypes.func,
    hideUndoAlert: PropTypes.func,
    lastSwippedElement: PropTypes.object,
    loading: PropTypes.bool,
    navigation: PropTypes.object,
    setSelectedAlert: PropTypes.func,
    setSelectedArticle: PropTypes.func,
    setSelectedEvent: PropTypes.func,
    setSelectedSurvey: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    undoSwipeAction: PropTypes.func,
    userEmailIsValidForVoterVoice: PropTypes.bool,
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.prompted = false;

    this.state = {
      refreshing: false,
      appState: AppState.currentState,
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
    if (!this.props.loading) {
      const doRefresh = await cache.shouldRefresh('feed');
      if (this.props.feed.length === 0 || doRefresh) {
        this.props.fetchFeed();
      }
      cache.incrementAppViews();
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  _handleAppStateChange = async appState => {
    if (
      this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) &&
      appState === 'active'
    ) {
      cache.incrementAppViews();
      const doRefresh = await cache.shouldRefresh('feed');
      if (doRefresh) {
        this.props.fetchFeed();
      }
    }
    this.setState({appState});
  };

  _keyExtractor = ({Entity}) =>
    (Entity.Key || Entity.Id || Entity.CampaignId || Entity.Code).toString();

  _gotoEvent = event => {
    cache.setRouteStarter('MainDrawer');
    this.props.setSelectedEvent(event);
    const title = `${event.LegislatureType} Event`;
    this.props.navigation.navigate('EventDetails', {title});
  };

  _gotoSurveyBallot = survey => {
    cache.setRouteStarter('MainDrawer');
    this.props.setSelectedSurvey(survey);
    this.props.navigation.navigate('SurveyDetails');
  };

  _gotoArticle = article => {
    cache.setRouteStarter('MainDrawer');
    this.props.setSelectedArticle(article);
    this.props.navigation.navigate('ArticleDetails');
  };

  _onAlertActionButtonPress = async item => {
    cache.setRouteStarter('MainDrawer');
    await this.props.setSelectedAlert(item.Entity);
    this.props.getCampaignDetails();
    if (this.props.userEmailIsValidForVoterVoice) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Questionnaire');
    } else {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('UnconfirmedEmail');
    }
  };

  _onSwipedOut = (swippedItem, index) => {
    this.props.handleContentSwipe(this.props, {swippedItem, index});
  };

  _handleGetInvolved = (response, entity) => {
    if (response !== entity.IsSelected) {
      const isTopic = entity.Category !== 'GetInvolved';
      const items = [
        {
          ...entity,
          IsSelected: response,
        },
      ];
      if (isTopic) {
        this.props.handleUpdateTopics({topics: items});
      } else {
        this.props.handleUpdateGetInvoved({involved: items});
      }
    }
  };

  renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
    const {Type, Entity} = item;
    if (Type === 'EVENT') {
      return (
        <SwippableCard onSwipedOut={() => this._onSwipedOut(item, index)}>
          <EventFeedCard
            style={styles.push}
            mainActionButtonPress={() => this._gotoEvent(Entity)}
            event={Entity}
          />
        </SwippableCard>
      );
    }

    if (['SURVEY_SURVEY', 'SURVEY_BALLOT'].includes(Type)) {
      return (
        <SwippableCard onSwipedOut={() => this._onSwipedOut(item, index)}>
          <SurveyBallotFeedCard
            style={styles.push}
            survey={Entity}
            handleViewDetails={() => this._gotoSurveyBallot(Entity)}
          />
        </SwippableCard>
      );
    }

    if (Type === 'SURVEY_MICRO') {
      return (
        <SwippableCard onSwipedOut={() => this._onSwipedOut(item, index)}>
          <MicroSurvey style={styles.push} selectedSurvey={Entity} />
        </SwippableCard>
      );
    }

    if (Type === 'ALERT') {
      return (
        <SwippableCard onSwipedOut={() => this._onSwipedOut(item, index)}>
          <ActionAlertFeedCard
            datePosted={Entity.StartDateUtc}
            style={styles.push}
            title={Entity.Headline}
            content={Entity.Alert}
            mainActionButtonPress={() => this._onAlertActionButtonPress(item)}
            secondaryActionButtonPress={() => {
              this.props.setSelectedAlert(Entity);
              // eslint-disable-next-line
              this.props.navigation.navigate("ActionAlertDetails", {
                content: Entity.Alert,
                id: Entity.CampaignId,
                title: Entity.Headline,
              });
            }}
          />
        </SwippableCard>
      );
    }

    if (Type === 'ARTICLE') {
      return (
        <SwippableCard onSwipedOut={() => this._onSwipedOut(item, index)}>
          <ArticleFeedCard
            content={Entity}
            style={styles.push}
            mainActionButtonPress={() => this._gotoArticle(Entity)}
          />
        </SwippableCard>
      );
    }

    //prettier-ignore
    if (Type === 'NOTIFICATION' && Entity.Code === 'INDIVIDUAL_ADDRESS_HOME_MISSING') {
      return (
        <MissingAddressCard
          style={styles.push}
          navigate={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeAddress')}
        />
      );
    }

    if (['PREFERENCE_TOPIC', 'PREFERENCE_INVOLVEMENT'].includes(Type)) {
      return (
        <SwippableCard onSwipedOut={() => this._onSwipedOut(item, index)}>
          <GetInvolvedFeedCard
            style={styles.push}
            title={Entity.DisplayText}
            onPress={response => this._handleGetInvolved(response, Entity)}
          />
        </SwippableCard>
      );
    }

    return null;
  };

  _onRefresh = async () => {
    try {
      this.setState({refreshing: true});
      this.props
        .fetchFeed()
        .then(() => {
          this.setState({refreshing: false});
        })
        .catch(() => {
          this.setState({refreshing: false});
        });
    } catch (e) {
      this.setState({refreshing: false});
    }
  };

  _trackScroll = async event => {
    try {
      if (this.prompted) {
        return;
      }

      const y = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
      const scrollHeight = height * 0.8;
      const page = Math.round(Math.floor(y) / scrollHeight);
      const alert = await cache.shouldPromtpPushNotificationPermissions();
      const iOS = Platform.OS === 'ios';

      if (alert && iOS && page > 1) {
        this.prompted = true;
        this._openPromptAlert();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  };

  _openPromptAlert = () => {
    Alert.alert(
      'Push Notifications Access',
      'Stay engaged with NFIB on the issues and activities you care about by allowing us to notify you using push notifications',
      [
        {
          text: 'Deny',
          onPress: () => {
            cache.pushNotificationsPrompted();
          },
          style: 'cancel',
        },
        {
          text: 'Allow',
          onPress: () => {
            OneSignal.registerForPushNotifications();
            cache.pushNotificationsPrompted();
          },
        },
      ],
      {cancelable: false}
    );
  };

  _getAlertTitle = () => {
    const {lastSwippedElement} = this.props;
    const {Type} = lastSwippedElement.swippedItem;

    if (Type.startsWith('PREFERENCE')) {
      return 'Preference Dismissed';
    }

    switch (Type) {
      case 'EVENT':
        return 'Event Dismissed';
      case 'SURVEY_BALLOT':
        return 'Ballot Dismissed';
      case 'SURVEY_SURVEY':
        return 'Survey Dismissed';
      case 'SURVEY_MICRO':
        return 'Micro Survey Dismissed';
      case 'ARTICLE':
        return 'Article Dismissed';
      case 'ALERT':
        return 'Action Alert Dismissed';
      default:
        return 'Dismissed';
    }
  };

  render() {
    if (this.props.loading && !this.state.refreshing) {
      return <Loading />;
    }

    const contentStyles =
      this.props.feed.length > 0 ? styles.content : emptyStateStyles.container;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          contentContainerStyle={contentStyles}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          data={this.props.feed}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
          removeClippedSubviews={false}
          onRefresh={this._onRefresh}
          refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
          ListEmptyComponent={() => (
            <EmptyState navigation={this.props.navigation} />
          )}
          scrollEventThrottle={100}
          onScroll={this._trackScroll}
        />
        {this.props.displayAlert && (
          <BottomAlert
            title={this._getAlertTitle()}
            onPress={this.props.undoSwipeAction}
            hideAlert={this.props.hideUndoAlert}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  content: {
    paddingHorizontal: scale(8),
    paddingTop: scale(16),
    paddingBottom: scale(20),
  },
  push: {
    marginBottom: 16,
  },
});

const mapState2Props = ({
  activityFeed,
  auth: {userEmailIsValidForVoterVoice},
  navigation,
}) => {
  return {
    ...activityFeed,
    userEmailIsValidForVoterVoice,
    loading: activityFeed.loading || navigation.deepLinkLoading,
  };
};

export default connect(mapState2Props, {
  fetchFeed,
  getCampaignDetails,
  handleUpdateGetInvoved,
  handleUpdateTopics,
  setSelectedAlert,
  setSelectedArticle,
  setSelectedEvent,
  setSelectedSurvey,
  handleContentSwipe,
  undoSwipeAction,
  hideUndoAlert,
})(ActivityFeed);
```

I don't see anything apparent with my code and I am wondering if it's some change that the `react-navigation` team did.

I am using `react-navigation` version 1.5.11 with `react-native` version 0.60.4.

Is this a compatibility issue with the RN version? Do I have no choice but to upgrade?

And this problem seems prevalent throughout my application. I also get the error here:

[image]

This is the `src/auth/screens/ResetLinkConfirmationAlert.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import ResetPasswordLinkConfirmationAlert from 'auth/components/ResetPasswordLinkConfirmationAlert';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const ResetLinkConfirmationAlert = ({resetEmail, navigation}) => {
  const {params} = navigation.state;
  return <ResetPasswordLinkConfirmationAlert email={resetEmail} {...params} />;
};

ResetLinkConfirmationAlert.propTypes = {
  navigation: PropTypes.object,
  resetEmail: PropTypes.string,
};

const mapStateToProps = ({registrations}) => {
  const {resetEmail} = registrations.resetPasswordData;
  const email = resetEmail || registrations.verificationEmail;
  return {resetEmail: email};
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ResetLinkConfirmationAlert);
```

and it's being imported here in `src/navigation/auth/stack.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import { StackNavigator, NavigationActions } from "react-navigation";
import { Intro } from "auth/screens/Intro";
import { Login } from "auth/screens/Login";
import { PasswordReset } from "auth/screens/PasswordReset";
import { RegisterNoEmail } from "auth/screens/RegisterNoEmail";
import AskForMembership from "auth/screens/AskForMembership";
import { CompleteAccount } from "auth/screens/CompleteAccount";
import { ConfirmMemberAccount } from "auth/screens/ConfirmMemberAccount";
import { Register } from "auth/screens/Register";
import SetNewPassword from "auth/screens/SetNewPassword";
import { RegisterEmailPassword } from "auth/screens/RegisterEmailPassword";
import ResetLinkConfirmationAlert from "auth/screens/ResetLinkConfirmationAlert";
import DetailsConfirmation from "auth/screens/DetailsConfirmation";
import AccountCreated from "auth/screens/AccountCreated";

import BackButton from "navigation-components/BackButton";
import CustomHeader from "navigation-components/CustomHeader";
import HeaderTitle from "navigation-components/HeaderTitle";
import { v2Colors } from "theme";
import { defaultStackConfig, defaultHeaderStyles } from "../config";

const leftRegiterNavOptions = {
  title: "Register",
  headerStyle: defaultStackConfig.authHeaderStyle
};

const stack = StackNavigator(
  {
    Intro: {
      screen: Intro,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null
      }
    },
    Register: {
      screen: Register,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        header: <CustomHeader onPress={() => navigation.goBack(null)} />,
        headerStyle: defaultStackConfig.authHeaderStyle
      })
    },
    RegisterNoEmail: {
      screen: RegisterNoEmail,
      navigationOptions: leftRegiterNavOptions
    },
    RegisterEmailPassword: {
      screen: RegisterEmailPassword,
      navigationOptions: leftRegiterNavOptions
    },
    AskForMembership: {
      screen: AskForMembership,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: <HeaderTitle />,
        headerStyle: defaultStackConfig.authHeaderStyle
      }
    },
    ConfirmMemberAccount: {
      screen: ConfirmMemberAccount,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        header: (
          <HeaderTitle
            headerLeft={() => (
              <BackButton onPress={() => navigation.goBack(null)} />
            )}
          />
        ),
        headerStyle: defaultStackConfig.authHeaderStyle
      })
    },
    CompleteAccount: {
      screen: CompleteAccount,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: <HeaderTitle />,
        headerStyle: defaultStackConfig.authHeaderStyle
      }
    },
    Login: {
      screen: Login,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: "Log In",
        headerLeft: <BackButton onPress={() => navigation.goBack(null)} />,
        headerStyle: defaultStackConfig.authHeaderStyle
      })
    },
    PasswordReset: {
      screen: PasswordReset,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: "Password Reset",
        headerLeft: <BackButton onPress={() => navigation.goBack(null)} />,
        headerStyle: defaultStackConfig.authHeaderStyle
      })
    },
    ResetLinkConfirmationAlert: {
      screen: ResetLinkConfirmationAlert,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: "Password Reset",
        headerLeft: (
          <BackButton
            onPress={() => {
              const resetNavAction = NavigationActions.reset({
                index: 0,
                key: null,
                actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: "Intro" })]
              });
              navigation.dispatch(resetNavAction);
            }}
          />
        ),
        headerStyle: defaultStackConfig.authHeaderStyle
      })
    },
```

Upgrading to `react-navigation` 2.0.0 is not the answer because I already tried that and if you are going to suggest upgrading to 3.x please explain how that will solve this issue.

It was suggested that in the changelog for react-redux 7.1.0 they mention a note stating `PropTypes.func` has to be changed to `PropTypes.elementType` if an element is being passed as a prop

github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/releases/tag/v7.0.1

So in the case where I am getting the error for `SetNewPassword`, I refactored it like so:

```
export class CompleteAccount extends PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    loading: PropTypes.bool,
    newConfirmResetPassword: PropTypes.string,
    newResetPassword: PropTypes.string,
    resetUserPassword: PropTypes.elementType.isRequired,
    setConfirnResetPassword: PropTypes.elementType.isRequired,
    setNewResetPassword: PropTypes.elementType.isRequired,
    validationErrors: PropTypes.object
  };
```

and then in `navigation/auth/stack.js` I added curly braces to the import statement like so:

```
import { SetNewPassword } from "auth/screens/SetNewPassword";
```

but I am still getting that error message, although I am not sure if I applied that correctly. At the same time I have noticed that `SetNewPassword.js` file only has the named export of `CompleteAccount`:

```
export class CompleteAccount extends PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    loading: PropTypes.bool,
    newConfirmResetPassword: PropTypes.string,
    newResetPassword: PropTypes.string,
    resetUserPassword: PropTypes.elementType.isRequired,
    setConfirnResetPassword: PropTypes.elementType.isRequired,
    setNewResetPassword: PropTypes.elementType.isRequired,
    validationErrors: PropTypes.object
  };
.......

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {
    resetUserPassword,
    setNewResetPassword,
    setConfirnResetPassword
  }
)(CompleteAccount);
```

Not sure how this file was working before in that manner. I usually name my files the same name as the class or functional screen and import it with the same name.

On further inspection I see that there are two screens with the same class name function.

`CompleteAccount.js`:

```
export class CompleteAccount extends PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    cellPhone: PropTypes.string,
    cellPhoneChanged: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    city: PropTypes.string,
    cityChanged: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    errors: PropTypes.object,
    firstName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    homeAddress: PropTypes.string,
    homeAddressChanged: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    homePhone: PropTypes.string,
    homePhoneChanged: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    registeredUser: PropTypes.object,
    registerUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    state: PropTypes.string,
    stateChanged: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    zipCode: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    zipCodeChanged: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };
```

which is exported as:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  cityChanged,
  homeAddressChanged,
  homePhoneChanged,
  cellPhoneChanged,
  stateChanged,
  zipCodeChanged,
  registerUser,
})(CompleteAccount);
```

and then there is `SetNewPassword.js`:

which is also named:

```
export class CompleteAccount extends PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    loading: PropTypes.bool,
    newConfirmResetPassword: PropTypes.string,
    newResetPassword: PropTypes.string,
    resetUserPassword: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    setConfirnResetPassword: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    setNewResetPassword: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    validationErrors: PropTypes.object
  };
.....

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {
    resetUserPassword,
    setNewResetPassword,
    setConfirnResetPassword
  }
)(CompleteAccount);
```

even though the file name is completely different. That is confusing, why didn't they just give the second one the class name of `SetNewPassword`?

Comment: What is the version of react-redux you are using

Comment: @Gokul, I am using `"react-redux": "7.1.0"`. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: In the changelog for react-redux 7.0.1 they have mention a note stating PropTypes.func has to be changed to PropTypes.elementType if an element is being passed as a prop https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/releases/tag/v7.0.1. Can you check if that is an issue in your case

Comment: @Gokul, I tried it. I added the details to the OP above.

Comment: Remove "export" keyword before Class in Main.js file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long grueling 6 days at this, and attempting fixes that went against our understanding of using curly braces when you got named exports, I always suspected that the problem was with `react-navigation` because I did not mess with the `react-navigation` version or the codebase.

The problem is how `react-navigation` works or does not work with `react-redux` version 7.

React Navigation does not recognize the object returned by React-Redux version 7.

The solution was to downgrade to React-Redux version 5.1.1.

Answer (score 2):

The immediate issue looks like the multiple exports in the component files. Try removing the `export` before the class definition and only keep `export default` at the end.

Regarding the confusion about `SetNewPassword.js` and `CompleteAccount.js` having the same exports, that'll not cause an issue as long you import the `default exported` component.

To put it simply,

If you export a component as `default`, then you can import it without the `{}` curly braces, like

```
import CompleteAccount from '.../CompleteAccount.js'
```

Here you can name the import anything you want.

If you use the curly braces, that'll import the `named export`, like

```
import {CompleteAccount} from '.../CompleteAccount.js'
```

Comment: I tried importing `Login` without curly braces because it has `export default connect(` as you say and I immediately get an error.