# TypeError: this.props.setLoginDisabled is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

There is a screen called `Login` that is passing in an action creator from `loginActions` like so:

https://gist.github.com/ldco2016/e2feedc5460e64e9b740af73cec5fe89

When I boot up the application and click on the Login button, I get the following error:

[image]

In the legacy version of the application, all this was working, no such error, but now when clicking the Login button in the upgraded 0.60.4 version, I get this error.

When I look at the `loginActions` file, I am wondering if there should be an `export default connect()()` and `mapDispatchToProps` in there to inject props into `Login` screen. So one of my questions is, do I indeed need this?

How did it work before? Was it passed down from the parent? This is the `loginActions.js` file:

```
import {Alert} from 'react-native';
import logger from 'logger';
import * as types from 'auth/constants';
import * as endpoints from 'endpoints';
import * as cache from 'utils/cache';
import {AUTH_STATUS} from 'enums/authStatus';
import * as requester from 'services/Requester';
import {clearSurveys} from 'surveys-ballots/actions';
import {clearEvents} from 'events/actions';
import * as repsActions from 'representatives/actions';
import {clearRegistration} from 'auth/registrationActions';
import {clearFeed} from 'activity-feed/actions';
import {clearActionAlerts} from 'action-alerts/actions';
import * as dataHelpers from 'auth/helpers/data-helpers';
import * as helpers from 'auth/helpers/actions-helpers';
import {verificationEmailChanged} from 'auth/registrationActions';
import {clearMembershipFields} from 'membership/actions';
import {
  setRelevantStates,
  clearPreferences,
} from 'account-settings/preferencesActions';
import {fetchPrefences, fetchTopics} from 'account-settings/preferencesActions';
import * as appcenter from 'utils/appcenterLogger';

export function setAuthStatus(authStatus) {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
      const {auth: {user}} = getState();
      dispatch({
        type: types.SET_AUTH_STATUS,
        payload: {
          ...user,
          authStatus,
        },
      });
      logger(types.SET_AUTH_STATUS);
    } catch (error) {
      logger('error in setAuthStatus');
      return false;
    }
  };
}

export function handleLogin({email, password, rememberEmail}) {
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
      dispatch({type: types.LOGIN_STARTED});
      logger(types.LOGIN_STARTED);

      const response = await requester.sendPost(endpoints.USER_LOGIN, {
        Username: email,
        Password: password,
      });

      const needsSetup = dataHelpers.needsSetup(response);

      if (needsSetup) {
        dispatch({
          type: types.EMAIL_VERIFICATION_SUBMIT_ENDED_SUCCESS,
          payload: response,
        });
        dispatch(verificationEmailChanged(email));
        return Promise.resolve({
          needsSetup: true,
        });
      }
      const user = {
        ...response,
        authStatus: AUTH_STATUS.LOGGED_IN,
      };

      cache.saveUserRef(user);
      cache.handleEmailCache(email, rememberEmail);

      helpers.sendOneSignalTags(user, true);
      appcenter.trackUser('UserLogin', user, true);

      dispatch({
        type: types.LOGIN_SUCCESS,
        payload: user,
      });

      const deepLinkedEvent = await cache.getDeepLinkedElement('event');
      const deepLinkedBallot = await cache.getDeepLinkedElement('survey');

      dispatchAfterLoginActions(dispatch, user);

      logger(types.LOGIN_SUCCESS);

      return Promise.resolve({
        needsSetup: false,
        deepLinkedEvent,
        deepLinkedBallot,
      });
    } catch (e) {
      logger(types.LOGIN_ERROR, e);
      const error = e && e.Message;
      dispatch({type: types.LOGIN_ERROR, payload: error});
    }
  };
}

export function checkSession(responseError) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const {auth: {user}} = getState();
    if (
      user.authStatus === AUTH_STATUS.LOGGED_IN &&
      responseError &&
      responseError.Message &&
      (responseError.Message.lastIndexOf('TokenExpired') >= 0 ||
        responseError.Message === 'Individual not found')
    ) {
      dispatch(handleLogout());
      return Alert.alert(
        'Session Timeout',
        'For your security, your NFIB session has timed out due to inactivity.',
        [{text: 'Ok', onPress: () => false}]
      );
    }
  };
}

export function handleLogout() {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const {auth: {user}} = getState();

    dispatch(clearSurveys());
    dispatch(clearEvents());
    dispatch(clearRegistration());
    dispatch(repsActions.clearRepresentatives());
    dispatch(clearFeed());
    dispatch(clearActionAlerts());
    dispatch(clearMembershipFields());
    dispatch(clearPreferences());
    dispatch({type: types.RESET_LOGIN_STATE});

    cache.clearCache();
    helpers.sendOneSignalTags(user, false);
    appcenter.trackUser('UserLogout', user, false);
    requester.resetTokenExpired();
  };
}

export function setCurrentUser({Key}) {
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
      dispatch({type: types.FETCH_USER_DETAILS_STARTED});
      const user = await helpers.fetchCurrentUserDetails(Key);
      dispatch({
        type: types.SET_CURRENT_USER,
        payload: {
          ...user,
          authStatus: AUTH_STATUS.LOGGED_IN,
        },
      });

      dispatchAfterLoginActions(dispatch, user);

      logger(types.SET_CURRENT_USER);
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: types.FETCH_USER_DETAILS_FINISHED_ERROR,
        payload: error,
      });
      dispatch(checkSession(error));
      logger(types.FETCH_USER_DETAILS_FINISHED_ERROR);
    }
  };
}

function dispatchAfterLoginActions(dispatch, user) {
  dispatch(fetchUserOrganizationDetails(user));
  dispatch(validateUserInformationForVoterVoice());
  dispatch(setRelevantStates());
  dispatch(fetchPrefences(user));
  dispatch(fetchTopics());
}

export function setUserMembership(user) {
  const isMember = Boolean(user.Organization && user.Organization.Key);
  return {
    type: types.SET_USER_MEMBERSHIP,
    payload: isMember,
  };
}

export function fetchUserOrganizationDetails(user) {
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
      if (user.Organization && user.Organization.Key) {
        const {Key} = user.Organization;
        const payload = await helpers.fetchOrganizationDetails(Key);
        dispatch({
          type: types.GET_USER_ORGANIZATION_FINISHED_SUCCESS,
          payload,
        });
        dispatch(setUserMembership(user));
        logger(types.GET_USER_ORGANIZATION_FINISHED_SUCCESS);
        helpers.sendOneSignalOrganizationTags(payload);
        cache.saveOrganizationData(payload);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      logger(types.GET_USER_ORGANIZATION_FINISHED_ERROR);
      dispatch({
        type: types.GET_USER_ORGANIZATION_FINISHED_ERROR,
        payload: error,
      });
      dispatch(checkSession(error));
    }
  };
}

export function setUserPosition(coords) {
  return {
    type: types.SET_USER_POSITION,
    payload: coords,
  };
}

export function setEmailField(email) {
  return {
    type: types.SET_EMAIL_FIELD,
    payload: email,
  };
}

export function setPasswordField(password) {
  return {
    type: types.SET_PASSWORD_FIELD,
    payload: password,
  };
}

export function setSecurityTextEntry(current) {
  return {
    type: types.SET_SECURITY_TEXT_ENTRY,
    payload: current,
  };
}

export function setLoginDisabled(status) {
  return {
    type: types.SET_LOGIN_DISABLED,
    payload: status,
  };
}

export function validateUserAddress() {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
      logger(types.VALIDATE_USER_ADDRESS_STARTED);
      dispatch({type: types.VALIDATE_USER_ADDRESS_STARTED});
      const {auth: {user: {PersonalAddress}}} = getState();
      const payload = await helpers.validateAddress({
        homeAddress: PersonalAddress.AddressLine1,
        city: PersonalAddress.City,
        state: PersonalAddress.StateCode,
        zipCode: PersonalAddress.PostalCode,
      });
      dispatch({type: types.VALIDATE_USER_ADDRESS_SUCCESS, payload});
      logger(types.VALIDATE_USER_ADDRESS_SUCCESS);
    } catch (error) {
      logger(types.VALIDATE_USER_ADDRESS_ERROR);
      dispatch({
        type: types.VALIDATE_USER_ADDRESS_ERROR,
        payload: error,
      });
      dispatch(checkSession(error));
    }
  };
}

export function validateUserInformationForVoterVoice(userKey = null) {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
      logger(types.VALIDATE_USER_INFORMATION_FOR_VOTER_VOICE_STARTED);
      dispatch({
        type: types.VALIDATE_USER_INFORMATION_FOR_VOTER_VOICE_STARTED,
      });

      const {auth: {user: {Key}}} = getState();
      const payload = await helpers.validateUserInformationForVoterVoice(
        userKey || Key
      );

      logger(types.VALIDATE_USER_INFORMATION_FOR_VOTER_VOICE_SUCCESS);
      dispatch({
        type: types.VALIDATE_USER_INFORMATION_FOR_VOTER_VOICE_SUCCESS,
        payload,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: types.VALIDATE_USER_INFORMATION_FOR_VOTER_VOICE_ERROR,
        payload: error,
      });
    }
  };
}

export function sendVerificationEmail() {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
      logger(types.SEND_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_STARTED);
      dispatch({type: types.SEND_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_STARTED});

      const {auth: {user: {Key}}} = getState();
      const payload = await helpers.sendVerificationEmail(Key);

      logger(types.SEND_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_SUCCESS);
      dispatch({
        type: types.SEND_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_SUCCESS,
        payload,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: types.SEND_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_ERROR,
        payload: error,
      });
    }
  };
}

export function toggleRememberEmail() {
  return {type: types.TOGGLE_REMEMBER_EMAIL};
}
```

This is the reducer:

```
import {AUTH_STATUS} from 'enums/authStatus';
import * as types from 'auth/constants';

export const INITIAL_STATE = {
  user: {
    authStatus: AUTH_STATUS.LOGGED_OUT,
  },
  error: null,
  loading: false,
  isMember: false,
  userOrganization: null,
  primaryIndividual: null,
  userPosition: null,
  email: '',
  password: '',
  useSecureTextEntry: true,
  isDisabled: false,
  validatingUserAddress: true,
  validatingUserAddressForVV: true,
  userAddressValid: true,
  userAddressIsValidForVoterVoice: false,
  userEmailIsValidForVoterVoice: false,
  rememberEmail: true,
};

//eslint-disable-next-line
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, {type, payload}) => {
  switch (type) {
    case types.LOGIN_STARTED:
      return {...state, loading: true, error: null};
    case types.LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return {...state, user: payload, loading: false};
    case types.LOGIN_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        error: payload,
      };
    case types.EMAIL_VERIFICATION_SUBMIT_ENDED_SUCCESS:
      return {...state, loading: false};
    case types.SET_CURRENT_USER:
      return {...state, loading: false, user: payload};
    case types.SET_AUTH_STATUS:
      return {...state, user: payload};
    case types.SET_USER_MEMBERSHIP:
      return {...state, isMember: payload};
    case types.GET_USER_ORGANIZATION_STARTED:
      return {...state, loading: true, error: null};
    case types.GET_USER_ORGANIZATION_FINISHED_SUCCESS:
      return {...state, loading: false, ...payload};
    case types.GET_USER_ORGANIZATION_FINISHED_ERROR:
      return {...state, loading: false, error: payload};
    case types.RESET_LOGIN_STATE:
      return INITIAL_STATE;
    case types.SET_USER_POSITION:
      return {...state, userPosition: payload};
    case types.FETCH_USER_DETAILS_STARTED:
      return {...state, loading: true, error: null};
    case types.FETCH_USER_DETAILS_FINISHED_ERROR:
      return {...state, loading: false, error: payload};
    case types.SET_EMAIL_FIELD:
      return {...state, email: payload};
    case types.SET_PASSWORD_FIELD:
      return {...state, password: payload};
    case types.SET_SECURITY_TEXT_ENTRY:
      return {...state, useSecureTextEntry: payload};
    case types.SEND_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_STARTED:
      return {...state, loading: true};
    case types.SEND_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_SUCCESS:
      return {...state, loading: false};
    case types.SEND_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_ERROR:
      return {...state, loading: false};
    case types.SET_LOGIN_DISABLED:
      return {...state, isDisabled: payload};
    case types.UPDATE_PERSONAL_DETAILS:
      return {
        ...state,
        user: {
          ...state.user,
          PersonalDetails: payload,
        },
      };
    case types.UPDATE_CONTACT_DETAILS:
      return {
        ...state,
        user: {
          ...state.user,
          ContactDetails: payload,
        },
      };
    case types.UPDATE_PERSONAL_ADDRESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        user: {
          ...state.user,
          PersonalAddress: payload,
        },
      };
    case types.VALIDATE_USER_ADDRESS_STARTED:
      return {...state, validatingUserAddress: true};
    case types.VALIDATE_USER_ADDRESS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        validatingUserAddress: false,
        userAddressValid: payload,
      };
    case types.VALIDATE_USER_ADDRESS_ERROR:
      return {...state, validatingUserAddress: false};
    case types.VALIDATE_USER_INFORMATION_FOR_VOTER_VOICE_STARTED:
      return {...state, validatingUserAddressForVV: true};
    case types.VALIDATE_USER_INFORMATION_FOR_VOTER_VOICE_SUCCESS: {
      const {
        userAddressIsValidForVoterVoice,
        userEmailIsValidForVoterVoice,
      } = payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        userAddressIsValidForVoterVoice,
        userEmailIsValidForVoterVoice,
        validatingUserAddressForVV: false,
      };
    }
    case types.VALIDATE_USER_INFORMATION_FOR_VOTER_VOICE_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        userAddressIsValidForVoterVoice: false,
        userEmailIsValidForVoterVoice: false,
        validatingUserAddressForVV: false,
      };
    case types.TOGGLE_REMEMBER_EMAIL:
      return {...state, rememberEmail: !state.rememberEmail};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

This is all inside of `src/auth`.

The `Login` screen is being used inside of `src/navigation/auth/stack.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import { StackNavigator, NavigationActions } from "react-navigation";
import { Intro } from "auth/screens/Intro";
import { Login } from "auth/screens/Login";
import { PasswordReset } from "auth/screens/PasswordReset";
import { RegisterNoEmail } from "auth/screens/RegisterNoEmail";
import AskForMembership from "auth/screens/AskForMembership";
import { CompleteAccount } from "auth/screens/CompleteAccount";
import { ConfirmMemberAccount } from "auth/screens/ConfirmMemberAccount";
import { Register } from "auth/screens/Register";
import { SetNewPassword } from "auth/screens/SetNewPassword";
import { RegisterEmailPassword } from "auth/screens/RegisterEmailPassword";
import { ResetLinkConfirmationAlert } from "auth/screens/ResetLinkConfirmationAlert";
import { DetailsConfirmation } from "auth/screens/DetailsConfirmation";
import { AccountCreated } from "auth/screens/AccountCreated";

import BackButton from "navigation-components/BackButton";
import CustomHeader from "navigation-components/CustomHeader";
import HeaderTitle from "navigation-components/HeaderTitle";
import { v2Colors } from "theme";
import { defaultStackConfig, defaultHeaderStyles } from "../config";

const leftRegiterNavOptions = {
  title: "Register",
  headerStyle: defaultStackConfig.authHeaderStyle
};

const stack = StackNavigator(
  {
    Intro: {
      screen: Intro,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null
      }
    },
    Register: {
      screen: Register,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        header: <CustomHeader onPress={() => navigation.goBack(null)} />,
        headerStyle: defaultStackConfig.authHeaderStyle
      })
    },
    RegisterNoEmail: {
      screen: RegisterNoEmail,
      navigationOptions: leftRegiterNavOptions
    },
    RegisterEmailPassword: {
      screen: RegisterEmailPassword,
      navigationOptions: leftRegiterNavOptions
    },
    AskForMembership: {
      screen: AskForMembership,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: <HeaderTitle />,
        headerStyle: defaultStackConfig.authHeaderStyle
      }
    },
    ConfirmMemberAccount: {
      screen: ConfirmMemberAccount,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        header: (
          <HeaderTitle
            headerLeft={() => (
              <BackButton onPress={() => navigation.goBack(null)} />
            )}
          />
        ),
        headerStyle: defaultStackConfig.authHeaderStyle
      })
    },
    CompleteAccount: {
      screen: CompleteAccount,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: <HeaderTitle />,
        headerStyle: defaultStackConfig.authHeaderStyle
      }
    },
    Login: {
      screen: Login,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: "Log In",
        headerLeft: <BackButton onPress={() => navigation.goBack(null)} />,
        headerStyle: defaultStackConfig.authHeaderStyle
      })
    },
```

It seems all the action creators inside of `loginActions` are coming back undefined for example `setAuthStatus` which is being used inside of `auth/screens/Intro.js`:

```
/* eslint react/forbid-prop-types: "off"*/
import React from "react";
import {
  View,
  Image,
  Keyboard,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  Text
} from "react-native";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { TextButton } from "react-native-material-buttons";
import { colors, v2ButtonStyles, v2Colors } from "theme";
import { Loading } from "common-components";
import { setAuthStatus } from "auth/loginActions";
import styles from "auth/styles";

const logo = require("icons/NFIB_white.png");

const propTypes = {
  loading: PropTypes.bool,
  navigation: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  setAuthStatus: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export class Intro extends React.Component {
  _dismiss = () => {
    Keyboard.dismiss();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this._dismiss}>
          <View style={{ flex: 1 }} accessible={true}>
            <Image
              source={logo}
              style={styles.v2Logo}
              accessible={true}
              accessibilityLabel={"imgLogo"}
            />
            {this.props.loading && <Loading />}
            {!this.props.loading && (
              <View style={styles.footerWrapper}>
                <View style={styles.authButtonsWrapper} accessible={true}>
                  <TextButton
                    color={v2Colors.green}
                    title={"LOG IN"}
                    titleColor={colors.white}
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Login")}
                    style={styles.authButton}
                    titleStyle={v2ButtonStyles.titleStyle}
                    accessibilityLabel={"btnLogin"}
                    accessibilityTraits={"button"}
                    accessibilityComponentType={"button"}
                  />
                  <Text style={styles.textSeparatorNewLine} />
                  <Text style={styles.textSeparatorNewLine}>
                    {" "}
                    {"First time here?"}
                  </Text>
                  <TextButton
                    color={v2Colors.green}
                    title={"REGISTER"}
                    titleColor={colors.white}
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Register")}
                    style={styles.authButton}
                    titleStyle={v2ButtonStyles.titleStyle}
                    accessibilityLabel={"btnRegister"}
                    accessibilityTraits={"button"}
                    accessibilityComponentType={"button"}
                  />
                </View>
              </View>
            )}
          </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

Intro.propTypes = propTypes;
const mapState2Props = ({ auth }) => {
  const { loading } = auth;
  return { loading };
};

export default connect(
  mapState2Props,
  {
    setAuthStatus
  }
)(Intro);
```

`setLoginDisabled` was not being dispatched:

```
export function setLoginDisabled(status) {
  return {
    type: types.SET_LOGIN_DISABLED,
    payload: status
  };
}
```

So I attempted to `dispatch` it like so:

```
export const setLoginDisabled = status => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch({ type: types.SET_LOGIN_DISABLED, payload: status });
};
```

and still got the same error as above. I don't think that made any difference.

So instead I decided to `console.log(setLoginDisabled)` right after its import statement and I got:

```
ƒ setLoginDisabled(status) {
    return {
      type: types.SET_LOGIN_DISABLED,
      payload: status
    };
  }
```

So it's definitely being defined when it's being imported. Then I tried:

```
// all this logic below will need to be consolidated into one `componentDidMount()`
  UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    console.log(this.props.setLoginDisabled);
    this.props.setLoginDisabled();
    this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      "keyboardDidShow",
      this._keyboardDidShow
    );
    this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      "keyboardDidHide",
      this._keyboardDidHide
    );
  }
```

and I am not really getting anything back.

I am starting to think that perhaps the issue is related to `require cycles` because I get a lot of warnings saying that a lot of the action creators in `loginActions` are undefined and I also get these warnings:

[image]

I think its a require cycle issue. So like File A wants something from File B -> File B wants something from File C -> File C wants something from File A. There is a circle being created and its leading to uninitialized values in my `loginActions.js` file, but I am not sure how to resolve it, if this is the case.

I am also getting the same error on the `android` side of things after pressing the Login button:

[image]

Android is much clearer in that indeed this action creator is undefined.

Comment: Can you share the code where login component is being used. Looks like it was being passed down by parent component. Also just to confirm, this login class file is complete, I am not seeing render method, So

Comment: @Garry, I shared the code where login screen is being imported above just now and I added the rest of the code to the `Login` screen.

Comment: Can I see import statements in ```Login``` class file

Comment: @Garry, just added it above.

Comment: @Daniel Can you share any warnings you get about cycles for `loginActions.js` specifically? Or the other related auth action creator files like `auth/registrationActions` to see if they are the source of a cycle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the `src/navigation/auth/stack.js`, a lot of the import statements are incorrect, they should not have curly brackets. I refactored the file like so:

```
import React from "react";
import { StackNavigator, NavigationActions } from "react-navigation";
import Intro from "auth/screens/Intro";
import Login from "auth/screens/Login";
import PasswordReset from "auth/screens/PasswordReset";
import RegisterNoEmail from "auth/screens/RegisterNoEmail";
import AskForMembership from "auth/screens/AskForMembership";
import CompleteAccount from "auth/screens/CompleteAccount";
import ConfirmMemberAccount from "auth/screens/ConfirmMemberAccount";
import Register from "auth/screens/Register";
import SetNewPassword from "auth/screens/SetNewPassword";
import RegisterEmailPassword from "auth/screens/RegisterEmailPassword";
import ResetLinkConfirmationAlert from "auth/screens/ResetLinkConfirmationAlert";
import DetailsConfirmation from "auth/screens/DetailsConfirmation";
import AccountCreated from "auth/screens/AccountCreated";

import BackButton from "navigation-components/BackButton";
import CustomHeader from "navigation-components/CustomHeader";
import HeaderTitle from "navigation-components/HeaderTitle";
import { v2Colors } from "theme";
import { defaultStackConfig, defaultHeaderStyles } from "../config";

const leftRegiterNavOptions = {
  title: "Register",
  headerStyle: defaultStackConfig.authHeaderStyle
};
```

When I corrected this, the error changed back to this:

[image]

And the issue with the above error was due to `react-navigation` not recognizing the object returned from `react-redux` version 7 as noted in my other post:

[The component for route 'ActivityFeed' must be a React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57189982/the-component-for-route-activityfeed-must-be-a-react-component)

Answer (score 0):

This is react-redux yeah?

Have you wrapped your Login component in a 'connect' wrapper.

{connect} from 'react-redux';

connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);

I'm not sure if your Login component knows which action to use, 'setLoginDisabled()', and consequently the reducer, 'SET_LOGIN_DISABLED', doesn't get fired. I just set up react-redux with react-native and I used the 'connect' wrapper and it worked just fine.

Might want to try, https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api/connect.md

Comment: the `Login` screen component does have a `connect()` function at the bottom. I did not originally include that part of the code, but you can see it above now.

Comment: Are you dispatching all of your actions to the store?

Comment: I believe i am, but I have noticed that most of the action creators inside that action creator file are returning undefined.

Comment: From the looks of it, setUserPosition(), setEmailField(), setPasswordField(), and setLoginDisabled() are not being dispatched. Try dispatching one of of them and see if your connect wrapper can now read it.

Comment: will give it a try, but `setAuthStatus()` is returning undefined as well upon application boot and that is being dispatched.

Comment: I just attempted to `dispatch` `setLoginDisabled` and I am still getting the same error. You can view details above.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass dispatch for map dispatch to props. Try like this :

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
     return {
        setLoginDisabled: (status) => dispatch({ type: types.SET_LOGIN_DISABLED , payload: status })
     }
}
//OR
export function setLoginDisabled(dispatch, status) {
  return dispatch({
    type: types.SET_LOGIN_DISABLED,
    payload: status,
  })
}
```

Then if you created `mapDispatchToProps` const  pass `mapDispatchToProps` to  second argument :

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps 
)(Login);
```

Otherwise:

```
export default connect(
     mapStateToProps,
     dispatch => {
         setLoginDisabled(dispatch, status)
     }
)(Login);
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it did not work. I also added some more information to the original post. I think its a `require cycle` issue.  So like File A wants something from File B -> File B wants something from File C -> File C wants something from File A. There is a circle being created and its leading to uninitialized values in my `loginActions.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not passing  `setLoginDisabled` into the connect function.

That's why `setLoginDisabled` "is" a function when you `console.log(setLoginDisabled)` but it "isn't" available on this.props (try `console.log(this.props.setLoginDisabled)` and it would return undefined).

You need to pass in `setLoginDisabled` together with the `setAuthStatus` like this

```
connect(
    mapState2Props, {
        setAuthStatus,
        "setLoginDisabled"
    }
)(Intro);
```

And this should make `setLoginDisabled` available on `this.props`

Hope that works for you.